# Play video from NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: video, zip, document, nsbundle, movieplayer

i have a problem in my app

i'm downloading a zip in my app and adding it on NSDocumentDirectory, this zip have some images and a movie.

I can access and show all images, but i can't play the video

if my video is on bundle directory i use this code and i can play the video

the code: 
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"videoName" ofType: @"mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:viewController];

it's work if my video is on bundle directory, but i tried many ways to play the video from NSDocumentDirectory.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the right path for your video resource?

Comment: Post the code that you're using for get the path in documents, maybe we can get an answer.

Comment: my code:

        NSString *fileURLWithPath:movie = [_documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1/1.mov"];
        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movie];
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *viewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:viewController];
        [viewController release];

but i dont know how, now it's worked!!! \o/

Comment: but i have another problem, i need play videos from youtube and it doesnt work, how can i adjust this code to play a youtube video?

Answer (score 2):

For Youtube Videos you can send the url to the shared application and this will open the video in the YouTube.app for iOS

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8ecN36Ffpc";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

this works also for this other type of youtube urls

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/K8ecN36Ffpc";
```

Comment: yeah i know how to open like this, but i want to open a youtube video without leave my app